# Unity playing run animation but retaining a t-posed model in the background

Tags: unity

I downloaded a character in Mixamo without any animations and then proceeeded to download a separate FBX with animation then without any mesh, so I have 2 FBX files.

I then proceeded to add the model in my scene, add an Animator component and create a AnimatorController. I add the animation in AnimatorController. Here it how it looks like:

[image]

So I'm expecting the model to run upon Play and it did but the problem is how its displaying. It looks like this:

[image]

The running animation is playing but there's another model at the background following the running model.

I don't know what's happening and what I did wrong. Any ideas, please?

BTW, Rig animation type is set to Generic. I tried Humanoid as well, still the same.

**EDIT:**

Added images of Heirarchy and Assets

[image]

[image]

**EDIT 2:**

[image]

Comment: Show us your object in the hierarchy. It looks like you've accidentally stacked two instances of the mesh in your scene.

Comment: @DMGregory: I've added an image of the Hierarchy and I added how my Assets looks like as well. After downloading in Mixamo, I just dragged them in in my Assets folder and then dragged to the Scene.

Comment: OK, I know what's causing it but I don't know why. When I added the Mesh Filter and Renderer and assign Beta_Surface mesh to the Filter, that happens. I added the renderer because I needed Renderer.Bounds in a script I attached to this character. 

Everything works as I need it to though if there is Mesh Filter and Renderer attached but the Renderer is unchecked. I thought being unchecked would be equal to the renderer not attached. Clearly I am not understanding how this renderer works.

Comment: I think I get it now, there's already a Skinned Mesh Renderer and the Mesh Renderer works when unchecked because mesh is still there just isn't rendered. So I shouldn't add a Mesh Renderer because there is a Skinned Mesh Renderer but the script I'm using returns null on Renderer.Bounds without adding the Mesh Renderer. Currently, this is my problem.

Comment: I can get around this by adding a Collider and then changing code to get Collider.Bounds instead of Renderer.Bounds but I wanted to avoid calling Physics.SyncTransforms (I use object's Transform.Translate). Is there any way I can get that bounds of the Skinned Mesh Renderer (that is in the child of 'xbot' prefab) from a script that is attached to 'xbot' prefab?

Comment: Is it safe to assume you tried asking the SkinnedMeshRenderer on your child object using  `GetComponentInChildren<SkinnedMeshRenderer>().bounds` or something similar?

Comment: @DMGregory: Hi, yeah I just did as I was about to update this Question. I was able to get the renderer using GetComponentInChildren<Renderer> but for some reason that I am currently debugging why, my raycasts which are based on the bounds don't get casted on the location I expect if I got the renderer from the child. I will debug some more, at least I have possible options now (collider or GetComponentInChildren). Thank you, btw.